# Leaflet scroll page when hitting map bounds

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I would like a drag event (on touch devices) to continue on the containg page when reaching the bounds of the map. A little bit like a div whith `overflow: scroll`.

This means as long as I'm within my maxBounds a drag inside the map would move the map. But as soon as I hit the bounds the drag should magically continue on the page.

My idea is to do something like this:

```
map.on('drag', e => {
  if (exeedsMaxBounds()) {
    map.dragging.dissable()
    // now pass event back to container
    // to scroll the page
  }
})

map.on('dragend', e => {
  map.dragging.enable()
})
```

As a bonus the map is inside an iFrame so I can't use `window.scrollBy(x, y)`.

Is this even possible?